# Thinking Sphinx rake ts:index:delta command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am setting up delta indexing with Thinking Sphinx 3, Sphinx 2, Rails 4, and PostgreSQL 9, to index and query 200M rows. Conceptually, I understood that I could "merge the delta indices back into the main index, in a fraction of the time taken to do a full index", but am not finding such a command. Two questions:

1) Does a command like `rake ts:index:delta` exists?

2) Does it really matter, or can I forever run against delta indexes?

Thank you,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

1. Sphinx does have the ability to merge indices, but Thinking Sphinx does not use that functionality - the last time I tried to implement such a feature, it was not reliable, but that was a handful of years ago. I'm certainly open to pull requests covering this now, but yeah, there is nothing implemented at this point in time. Thus, no rake task covering such behaviour.
2. Even with delta indices, you still need to run a full index regularly - otherwise, your delta indices will grow and grow in size as more records are changed and added, getting slower to process, and thus the advantage of them is lost.

Hope this helps to clarify things.